# How to refresh CSS body animation from one particular link?

Tags: css, animation, button, refresh

My page has a CSS animation that changes the body color gradually. There are multiple links on the page, however I would like only one of those links to act as a refresh button for the animation.

I have made a fiddle to illustrate the concept. I'm sure it is a relatively simple fix, properly assigning class or ID tags, but I am stuck. Thanks in advance!

```css
a {
  color:white;
  }

/*Animation Prefs*/
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
0% {background-color: #09765a;}
100% {background-color: #000;}  
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse_m {
0% {background-color: #09765a;}
100% {background-color: #000;}  
}
body {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 5s linear;
  -moz-animation: pulse_m 5s linear;
  background-color: #000;
}

/*Animation Prefs 2*/
@-webkit-keyframes pulse2 {
0% {background-color: #09765a;}
100% {background-color: #000;}  
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse_m2 {
0% {background-color: #09765a;}
100% {background-color: #000;}  
}

 body:active {
  -webkit-animation: pulse2 5s linear;
  -moz-animation: pulse_m2 5s linear;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" rel="home_page">This link should refresh animation</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="#" rel="home_page">This link should not</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ykrtajep/

Comment: you need javascript for this. a child cannot update a parent's CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element on the concerned link:

```css
a {
  color: white;
}

#flash::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -99;
  animation: pulse 5s linear;
  background-color: #000;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#flash:active::before {
  animation-name:pulse2;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #09765a;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    background-color: #09765a;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="flash" rel="home_page">This link should refresh animation</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="#" rel="home_page">This link should not</a>
```